# Problems after oving Pyro CMS

Tags: php, content-management-system, pyro

a friend ask me to move his website ( Pyro CMS ) to my server.
I've made a Backup and then uploades all the files and the SQL file. but after that when i'm trying to enter the website this error appears:

```
**A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$bootstrap_image
Filename: drivers/Streams_parse.php
Line Number: 101**
```

The code of those lines are this:

```
    if ($fields)
    {
        foreach ($fields as $field)
        {
            if (method_exists($this->CI->type->types->{$field->field_type}, 'plugin_override'))
            {
                $content = preg_replace('/\{\{\s?'.$field->field_slug.'\s?/', '{{ streams_core:field row_id="{{ '.
                    $id_name.' }}" stream_slug="'.
                    $stream_slug.'" field_slug="'.$field->field_slug.'" namespace="'.
                    $stream_namespace.'" field_type="'.$field->field_type.'" ', $content);

                $content = preg_replace('/\{\{\s?\/'.$field->field_slug.'\s?\}\}/', '{{ /streams_core:field }}', $content);
            }
        }   
    }
```